# Proving properties of logarithm using integral form

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, proof-writing, logarithms

Let:
$$L(x) = \int_1^x\frac{1}{u}du$$
we are trying to show that $L(x^b) = bL(x)$

I was trying:
$$L(x^b) = \int_1^{x^{b}}\frac{1}{u}du = \int_1^{x}\frac{1}{u}du + \int_x^{x^{b}}\frac{1}{u}du$$

Let's focus on the last term using $u = bt$ and $dt = bdt$:

$$\int_x^{x^{b}}\frac{1}{u}du = \int_{ t =\frac{x}{b}}^{ t =\frac{x^b}{b}}\frac{1}{bt}bdt$$

but this did not work out in showing the last form has the correct form

Comment: Your lower limit cannot be $0$. It is often taken to be $1$.

Comment: First, lower bound in the definition should be $1.$ Second, try using a substitution to get the desired outcome.

Comment: @DarrylJohnson which one you suggest

Comment: I was trying to use $ u = b^2t$ in order to get the b out of the integral, but this did not work out in the limits of integration

Comment: Hint (I haven't tried). Consider differentiating, use the fundamental theorem of calculus and the chain rule.

Comment: actually, first of all, how are you defining $x^b$? and what do you already know about its properties? This will affect what constitutes a valid proof given your background. What we can do, relatively easily, using the FTC (as suggested above) is prove that $L(xy)=L(x)+L(y)$ for all $x,y>0$.

Comment: @peek-a-boo $b$ is any real number

Comment: that’s not what I asked

Comment: @peek-a-boo let's assume we know the product rule of logarithms

Comment: you’re still not answering my question. How did you **define** the symbol $x^b$? Do you already know how to define it? Do you know that resulting function is differentiable on $(0,\infty)$? Do you know its derivative is $bx^{b-1}$? If not for this, what other properties of such exponentiation have you proved already? Without answering any of these things, any “proof” is likely to end up being a circular mess.

Comment: @peek-a-boo let's assume everything excpet the power rule of logarithm

Comment: $u=t^b$ should work.  You get $du = bt^{b-1}$ and $x^b = t^b$ then implies the upper bound becomes $t.$

Comment: @ Ethan Bolker If I'm not wrong, your direction is correct. But proving the derivative of both sides are the same can only imply that the two expressions differ by a constant. To prove that constant is $0$, we can substitute in $x=1$, which yields $0=0$.

Comment: @DarrylJohnson we have to use the power rule of logarithms in changing the variable of the limits of integration

Comment: @peek-a-boo what definition would you suggest

Comment: I don’t see why you do?  The only thing you’re using is the fact that, on the interval of integration, the function $f(x) = x^b$ is one-to-one.  This can be proved without the log rule.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To prove $$\int_1^{x^b}{\frac{1}{u} du}=b\int_1^{x}{\frac{1}{u} du} $$

we put $u=v^b$,

then $du= b v^{b-1} dv$,

$u=1 \implies v=1$ and $u=x^b \implies v=x $

$\therefore$
\begin{align}
\int_1^{x^b}{\frac{1}{u} du} & = \int_1^{x}{\frac{bv^{b-1}}{v^b} dv} \\
 & = b\int_1^{x}{\frac{1}{v} dv} \\ 
 & = b\int_1^{x}{\frac{1}{u} du} \\
\end{align}

Comment: Can you explain how you find the limits of integration

Answer (score 0):

Using $s=u/x$ then $xds=du$

$$\int_x^{x^{b}}\frac{1}{u}du = \int_1^{x^{b-1}}\frac{1}{sx}xds=\int_1^{x^{b-1}}\frac{1}{s}ds$$

Comment: where is the constant b?

Comment: also the limits must be from 1 to $x^b$